# Best practice to manage state in Angular 2/4/6 application

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-forms, angular-directive

I am new to angular but an project has been assigned to me so i've started working on it but i am facing a situation related to state management so after authentication through wcf Restful service an Token is provided to user. so i can handle this with these 3 approaches.

- Session-storage
- Cookies
- local storage

  The **problem** with above approaches are --
- if i use **session state** it will not valid for new tab in a browser so i can't check if the token is exist or not
- if i use of **local storage** it won't work if user closes browser and get away from his/her system and later on someone else open his browser then it will be obviously a security threat.
- if i use of **cookies** it was working fine till now until i face an weird issue my child component was being authenticated through **authguard** by using of **canActivateChild** function.
  but when i **pasted the url** (along with child component path) **in a new tab** then both page were same in both tab and when i **clicked on Log out button** from **second tab** it was not removing the cookies.

**Note:** function is being called each time i click on log out button but it is not working in second tab and from first tab it works fine.

Comment: How exactly are you removing the cookie?

Comment: Logout()
  {
    this.cookieService.deleteAll();
    this.router.navigate(['/sign-in']);
  }

Comment: Looks like an issue with `ngx-cookie-service` in that case.

Comment: this type of questions are not good for SO as it's subjective and involves a lot of details and considerations, I suggest you ask it on Reddit, you''ll have a better chance of getting an answer there

Answer (score 0):

The best approach will be Ngrx , if you are in Angular, Previously it was Redux. Now we have Ngrx also you can use Ngrx device tools as chrome extension to see the state and action when your application will load.. it's awesome.

Comment: Thanks @Kumar-Gaurav, i'll try this but can you please tell me it will not lose the state if i refresh the page or open the same page in multiple url ?

Comment: State is something it will hold the value till your Application life cycle, Ex: You call one Api subscribe it then Dispatch the action using effect class so it will update the store with the data, so when u refresh the page it will not loose data , that you can see after downloading Redux crime device tool extension, When u need that data do Store.select , so it will return you the observables obj so subscribe and use it

Comment: You can do multiple Api and Dispatch all the data in store using difft ActionType..

Comment: Which thing have you used ??

Comment: Ngrx, but i couldn't find a way to logout user instantly if browser closed accidentally, because TokenId is saved in localstorage and you can't get it back if you'll refresh the page.

Comment: Refresh page will clear your storage in browser. So need to think something about that